# ASP.NET MVC 4 Membership Database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, membership

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 app. My database is hosted on Windows Azure. My solution has a new SQL Server Database project. I want to start off by adding adding the ASP.NET Membership functionality to this Database [project]. My question is, how do I do that?

I thought it would be a straight forward drag and drop operation. However, I cannot figure out how to do this basic task. All of the online videos I find demonstrate how to to implement the login via the ASP.NET MVC side. However, I don't see anything that shows setting up the Membership tables/sprocs/views and getting them in a SQL Server Database project.

Thank you for any insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template for creating an MVC 4 Internet application with forms-based authentication uses both the traditional ASP.NET Membership database with an additional layer on top called SimpleMembership, which has its own database.  The SimpleMembership database uses Entity Framework code-first model which creates the database automatically the first time you start the application.  Since SimpleMembership uses code-first the database schema can be modified by changing the UserProfile class in AcccountModels.cs. What is your objective for putting these databases that are handled by the application into a separate database project?  Unless you are going to bypass SimpleMembership any solution will have to handle two databases.

Comment: Ignorance on my part :). It sounds like I need to investigate SimpleMembership further.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the script(s) necessary for adding membership to a database using `aspnet_regsql` in your framework folder (usually `%windows%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\`). An example usage for producing the .sql file would be:

```
...\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regsql -sqlexportonly MembershipScript.sql
```

From there, run that script against your database. You may also need to play with the `-d <database>` flag, but all options can be shown using `aspnet_regsql -?`. (This includes exporting the necessary tables for session state and other options).

*I hope that's what you were asking but if I've misunderstood the question please clarify and I'll do my best to revise the answer*

Comment: Ooops- I think you forgot an option:
-sqlexportonly <filename>
Generate the SQL script file for adding or removing the specified features and do not carry out the actual operation. Can be used with the following options: -A, -R, -ssadd, and -ssremove.

-A all|m|r|p|c|w  Add support for a feature. Multiple values can be specified together. For example:
-A mp
-A m -A p

all: All features
m: Membership
r: Role manager
p: Profiles
c: Personalization
w: SQL Web event provider